# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable for GoogleTranslate API call

Tags: python, pandas, translate

I have a code - where i need to translate a particular column of a dataframe with Google translate API
Below is the code.

```
def TranslateText(text):
    #translator = Translator()
    translated_Text = translator.translate(text, src='tl', dest='en')
    #translated_Text = translated.text
    return translated_Text.text

CaseDF['TRANSLATED_VOICE_OF_CUSTOMER'] = CaseDF['WOCAS'].apply(TranslateText)
```

This column- 'WOCAS' is VOice of customer has more than 17K rows. no NAN values

Example values in VOCAS = [
'UPDATE KO LANG YUNG SA MGA BAGONG PROMO PO MAAM KAGAYA NANG UCT50 PO MAAM ',
'WOCAS: MAAM MAY DOWN BA KAYU SA CIGNAL? '
]

ERRROR
++++++++++++

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-fb90a8ed562c> in <module>
----> 1 CaseDF['TRANSLATED_WOCAS'] = CaseDF['WOCAS'].apply(TranslateText)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4198             else:
   4199                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4200                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4201 
   4202         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-14-ac56bb436f63> in TranslateText(text)
      5       'translate.google.co.in',
      6     ])
----> 7     translated_Text = translator.translate(text, src='tl', dest='en')
      8     #translated_Text = translated.text
      9     return translated_Text.text

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py in translate(self, text, dest, src, **kwargs)
    180 
    181         origin = text
--> 182         data = self._translate(text, dest, src, kwargs)
    183 
    184         # this code will be updated when the format is changed.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py in _translate(self, text, dest, src, override)
     76 
     77     def _translate(self, text, dest, src, override):
---> 78         token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
     79         params = utils.build_params(query=text, src=src, dest=dest,
     80                                     token=token, override=override)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py in do(self, text)
    193     def do(self, text):
    194         self._update()
--> 195         tk = self.acquire(text)
    196         return tk

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py in acquire(self, text)
    138         a = []
    139         # Convert text to ints
--> 140         for i in text:
    141             val = ord(i)
    142             if val < 0x10000:

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

++++++++++++
```

Comment: add `print(text)` at the top of `TranslateText` function and tell us when does it crash, most likely you have some int values in `WOCAS,` as with the provided example all should run just as fine.

Comment: This is from Google Translate PyPi package. I cannot add print statement in that.

Comment: TranslateText is not your function? I doubt that...

Comment: Yeah, i got it. But any kind of translation system should take care to translate even integers and if no translate found.. just leave as is.
i think, i will try by cleaning the data to remove "\n" and "numerics"

Comment: well, the last function aquire() is trying to convert the text (string array /sentence/) to integers, but variable text is set to integer according to error, thus it seems you have an int somewhere, that's why I recommend you to print out text to see when does it crash